# BigQuery read is Slow in Google DataFlow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For our Near real time analytics, data will be streamed into pubsub and Apache beam dataflow pipeline will process by first writing into bigquery and then do the aggregate processing by reading again from bigquery then storing the aggregated results in Hbase for OLAP cube Computation.

Here is the sample ParDo function which is used to fetch record from bigquery

```
String eventInsertedQuery="Select count(*) as usercount from <tablename> where <condition>";
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig
=QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(eventInsertedQuery).build();
TableResult result =  bigquery.query(queryConfig);
FieldValueList row = result.getValues().iterator().next();
LOG.info("rowCounttt {}",row.get("usercount").getStringValue());
```

bigquery.query is taking aroud ~4 seconds. Any suggestions to improve it? Since this is near real time analytics this time duration is not acceptable.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a custom ParDo to make an RPC to bigquery and pull in data, rather than using the built in BigQueryIO.Read, is there a reason why you are doing that? With that approach it will take a few secord to make the RPC, if you are doing this the process function this is called for every element, and will make the entire pipeline very slow. Is it possible to use BigQueryIO.Read instead which is optimized to pull in rows from batch and then parallelize the processing in the pipeline?

Comment: You can either read in the whole table or provide a custom query to BigQueryIO.Read. Then performa computation and aggregation in the Dataflow pipeline based on the elements that are output from BigQueryIO.Read https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Read.html

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the info If we use BigQueryIO.readTableRows(), it can only be applied to pipeline. For this use case, when ever message is streaming to pubsub, we need to query BigQuery and do the processing. Right now BigQueryIO.readTableRows() can only be applied in pipeline, if so it will run only only once, but for our use case if hase to be run whenever message is streamed in pubsub. Any suggestion Alex?

Comment: @AlexAmato any suggestions?

Comment: Does your bigquery table have static/master data that you want to use for lookups in your pipeline  ?

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman No we do not have static master data. All we have is one BigQuery table, where the  Raw Streaming data from pubsub will be stored in bigquery , and we read the same bigquery table , do the aggregation and Store it in Hbase Table.

Comment: I recommend creating a pipeline where you read from two sources, PubSub and BigQueryIO.Read. Then perform a Window to time bound the data (you can't join unboudned/infinite streaming data) the data and perform a CoGroupByKey to join the pubsub elements with bigquery rows using a key. After joining the data and computing what you want, output that to a Sink, perhaps using BigQueryIO.Write. See Windowing, CoGroupByKey, etc. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

Comment: @AlexAmato - I think the OP is ingesting data from Pub/Sub and writing it to BQ in the raw format in Step 1. Then in Step 2 reading from the BQ table perform some aggregates and write it into Bigtable. Based on this understanding they can read from PubSub write the raw data to BQ and then on the same data perform windowing and aggregation and write it into Bigtable without the need for reading from BQ.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on how much data you are looking up for each key in the BigQuery table. You could compute a side input, with the data for each key. Then in a ParDo which received the PubSub events as input and the side input (with the derived BigQuery data) you can lookup the side input data efficiently from data cached in memory.

See Side Inputs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs and look for some examples on pvalue.AsDict pvalue.AsSingleton pvalue.AsList

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman yes, I believe the same thing could be accomplished without first writing it all to BigQuery, if there is a need to also join it with the PubSub data then I believe that one of the above approaches will work. If you also want to keep a copy of the original PubSub data in pubsub that could be either a separate pipeline or a separate set of transforms in the same pipeline

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman, if we read from pubsub directly and do the aggregation , then we will miss the old records present in bigquery, that also need to considered for aggregation

Comment: @krthk - how long do you need to go back for your aggregation ? Can you share a sample usecase ?

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman Consider the case of an  online Examination , where students take up multi module exam, as and when they complete sections in that module the records will be streamed into pubsub and the overall progress which is nothing but aggregation has to be shown immediately , like how many modulules they have completed etc...

Comment: This can be solved with Windows & Triggering as explained here - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing. In case you are not able to solve for using windows and triggers then you can store the results in BQ table and then run a separate Dataflow job every 10 minutes to read from the BQ table , do the aggregation and write it it to Cloud Bigtable.

Comment: Consider using table partitioning to speed up BQ queries https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables - this will also *lower* your Bigquery bill.

Answer (score 2):

Frequent reads from BigQuery can add undesired latency in your app. If we consider that BigQuery is a data [warehouse for Analytics](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse#service_model_comparison), I would think that 4 seconds is a good response time. I would suggest to [optimize the query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview) to reduce the 4 seconds threshold.

Following is a list of possibilities you can opt to:

1. Optimizing the query statement, including changing the Database schema to add [partitioning or clustering](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-bigquery-queries-by-optimizing-the-schema-of-your-tables-e4c36077fa2d).
2. Using a relational database provided by [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features) for getting better response times.
3. Changing the architecture of you app. As recommended in comments, it is a good option to transform the data before writing to BQ, so you can avoid the latency of querying the data twice. There are several articles to perform Near Real Time computation with Dataflow (e.g. [building real time app](http://[https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-a-real-time-quant-trading-engine-on-google-cloud-dataflow-and-apache-beam-841a909d2c12]) and [real time aggregate data](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-efficiently-process-both-real-time-and-aggregate-data-with-dataflow)).

On the other hand, keep in mind that the time to finish a query is not included in the BigQuery [SLAs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla) webpage, in fact, it is expected that errors can occur and consume even more time to finish a query, see Back-off Requirements in the same link.